# Checking if a regex matched with RoR?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this RoR code as follows;

```
1. error_regex = /\|FileName.exe\|((dlg|frm|cls).*?)/
2. error_regex.match(backtrace)
3. if !error_regex.nil?
4.    file_name = error_regex[1].sub!(/\.zip/, '')
5.    file_name
6. end
```

So my question is, whats happening on line 3 here.
I have basically zero RoR experience, so looking at this code I read it as
If error_regex.nil is not nil then continue

but whats the ? for
couldn't I just do

```
if !error_regex.nil
```

The regex are all fine, I am just trying to get my head around this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question mark is used to indicate that the method, by convention, returns a boolean. Similar examples are `include?` for Arrays, (returns `true` if the array has the given element in it), `empty?` for Strings (returns `true` if the `string == ""`), and `zero?` for Integers (returns `true` if the int is zero).

So it's not Rails specific - it's Ruby-specific.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is part of the name of the method. Without it, you are calling an entirely different method. The question mark doesn't actually *do* anything, it's just a convention, as Chris Bunch said. But because Ruby has named the method `nil?`, you have to call it that way.